# Javascript chaining window.onload functions

Tags: javascript, function, dom, onload, chaining

I have a javascript function that grabs a dataset numeric value and appends it to an XMLhttprequest parameter. It has to run onload as the content is printed dynamically through php.

I now am trying to create a simple carousel for the elements printed and finding some difficulty chaining onload functions.

I've found creating an additional onload function for anything breaks the first onload function. What can I do here?

```
function userData() {
  let infoWrap = document.querySelector(".agent-detail-info").dataset.id;
  console.log(infoWrap);
  return infoWrap;
}
window.onload = userData;

window.onload = () => {
  const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open(
    "GET",
    `url&usertolookup=${userData()}`
  );

  request.onload = function () {
    let response = request.response;
    let parsedData = JSON.parse(response);
    console.log(parsedData);

    let testimonials = parsedData.data.testimonials.details;

    testimonials.forEach((testimonial, index) => {
      const testimonialWrap = document.querySelector(".testimonials");
      // Create testimonials container
      let innerTestimonials = document.createElement("div");
      innerTestimonials.className = "inner-testimonial-container";
      testimonialWrap.appendChild(innerTestimonials);

      // Create star rating container
      let starWrap = document.createElement("div");
      starWrap.className = "testimonial-stars";
      innerTestimonials.appendChild(starWrap);

      // Create Testimonial Content
      let innerTestimonialParagraph = document.createElement("p");
      innerTestimonials.appendChild(innerTestimonialParagraph);

      // Create Testimonial Signature
      let innerTestimonialSignature = document.createElement("address");
      innerTestimonials.appendChild(innerTestimonialSignature);

      // Loop through rating value and create elements
      let rating = testimonial.rating;
      for (let i = 0; i < rating; i++) {
        let star = document.createElement("i");
        star.className = "fa fa-star";
        starWrap.appendChild(star);
      }

      // Insert Testimonial Content
      let testimonialText = testimonial.Testimonial;
      innerTestimonialParagraph.innerHTML = testimonialText;

      // Insert Testimonial Signature
      let signature = testimonial.Signature;
      innerTestimonialSignature.innerHTML = signature;
    });
  };
  request.send();
};
```

Testing Carousel (have tried alternative with event listeners rather than inline onclick and cannot access the elements printed through the response(returns undefined as the elements are printed after dom load))

```
let tabIndex = 1;

function nextTestimonial(n) {
  testimonialSlide((tabIndex += n));
}

function currentTestimonial(n) {
  testimonialSlide((tabIndex = n));
}

function testimonialSlide(n) {
  let innerTestimonials = document.querySelectorAll(
    ".inner-testimonial-container"
  );

  if (n > innerTestimonials.length) {
    tabIndex = 1;
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    tabIndex = innerTestimonials.length;
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < innerTestimonials.length; i++) {
    innerTestimonials[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  innerTestimonials[tabIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
}
```

Random attempt to chain onload functions (this breaks the response)

```
window.onload = () => {
  const innerTestimonialsNew = document.querySelectorAll(
    ".inner-testimonial-container"
  );
  console.log(innerTestimonialsNew);
};
```

Comment: Use `window.addEventListener("load", yourFunction)` instead of setting the `onload` attribute. You can add as many event listeners as you want that way.

Comment: This works, but does not solve the problem - changing all onload to the event listener still results in being unable to call on the elements printed by the request.onload function

Comment: Ok, using event listeners and adding the console.log(innerTestimonialsNew) to the request function works